# How do I shuffle a string in Unity C#

Tags: c#, string, unity-container, shuffle

Is there a simple way in Unity C# to shuffle the alphabet letters in a string? This is to create a shuffled version of a string.

Comment: Show us your attempt or cheat and just search for one of the 1000 answers for this already.

Comment: I've been searching for a couple days and tried about 50 examples, including several versions of my own. Right now, I'm back to an empty function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is good! Learning through trial and error is really the best way to learn. But you need to try and find out what you did wrong. That lesson will stick to you for life. Show us your best attempt.

Answer (score -1):

Google Fisher-Yates and you'll find this.

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):   
    for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

That should be easy enough to translate into c#

Comment: Or just look at the C# implementation provided by duplicate questions on this site.

Comment: Except is't not possible to modify a string. So to use this you have to create an array of characters from the string, shuffle the array, and then convert back to string. To make this a complete answer, you should include that information.

Answer (score -1):

order your string by something unpredictable

```
var oldString = "shuffle";
var shuffled = new string(oldString.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray());

//shuffled = "feflhus"
```

Comment: Interesting but slow way :)

Comment: but `simple` IMHO :)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to fit that in the comment too ;p

Comment: I didn't know there was a string OrderBy in Unity C#.

Comment: @jadkins4 there isn't, its part of C#.

Comment: @jadkins4: More specifically, `string` implements `IEnumerable<Char>`, so `oldString.OrderBy(lambda)` resolves to `Enumerable.OrderBy(oldString, lambda)`.

Comment: Since I didn't find any real answers, I came up with my own solution
 Crude, but it works.
 
 static string ScrambleWord(string sWord)
 {
  int i;
  int j;
  string c;
  int iLen;
  int iRand;
  string newWord="";
  char[] charArray;

  iLen = sWord.Length;

  char[] chars = sWord.ToCharArray();

  for (i=0;i<chars.Length-1; i++)
  {
   for(j=0;j<chars.Length-1;j++)
   {
    char swap = chars[j];
    chars[j] = chars[j+1];
    chars[j+1] = swap;
   }
  }

  for(i=0;i<sWord.Length;i++)
  {
   //Debug.Log (chars[i]);
   newWord = newWord + chars[i].ToString();
  }

  return newWord;
 }

Comment: @jadkins4 If that's a solution to your problem, perhaps you should enter it as an answer.

Comment: I would, but there is no longer an answer button on this topic.